# Excel VBA / Deleting cells if their value doesn't with value from reference cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with an Excel/VBA macro. I have a single character value in column A (1,2,3,A,B,C etc) and need the values from the same row in columns B,C,D to be deleted (Shift:=xlToLeft) if they don't start with the specific character from column A.

So this here:

```
| 1 | 12345 | 23456 
| 3 | 42280 | 42280 
| 2 | 20613 | 20614 | 33221
| 5 | 51953 | 
| 2 | 21895 | 22222 | 28932
| 7 | 70119 | 61002 
| A | A1111 | 70142
```

should be turned into this here:

```
| 1 | 12345 |   
| 3 |   
| 2 | 20613 | 20614 |
| 5 | 51953 | 
| 2 | 21895 | 22222 | 28932
| 7 | 70119 |   
| A | A1111 |
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: have you tried anything? We need to see the code you have

Comment: Sorry Ibo I was too ashamed of myself to post it :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can't test this at the moment because I'm on mobile, but this should work, assuming that you are starting in cell A1

```
Dim rCheck As Range, i As Integer, iCol As Integer

Set rCheck = Range("A1") 'top left cell of your table
iCol = 5 'width of your table

Do While rCheck <> ""
   For i = 2 To iCol
        If Cells(rCheck.Row, i) <> "" And Left(Cells(rCheck.Row, i), 1) <> Left(rCheck.Value2, 1) Then
                Cells(rCheck.Row, i).Delete (xlToLeft)
                i = i - 1
                End If
   Next i
Set rCheck = rCheck.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much Plaidpenguinhat! I've tried to do this myself for hours, but your construction is the first one to actually work. However, it just works if the character in column A is a letter, not a number. Do you happen to have an idea why? I can't work it out. Also the whole thing doesn't work anymore when I replace .ClearContents by .Delete shift:=xlToLeft. It wouldn't go through all the rows anymore. I assume that's connected to the .offset-thing.

Comment: this will work, just needed to be more specific about the charater it was checking against. Also changed to .delete